# Facebook-scraper UnexpectedResponse

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, web-scraping, request

I want to scrape fanpage comment content so use this python package,but got something wrong

Here is my code

I think maybe proxy problem?so I take a free proxy,but it doesn't work

```
import requests
from http import cookiejar
import facebook_scraper as fb
file ='facebook.com_cookies.txt'
cookie = cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar()
cookie.load(file)
cookies =requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(cookie)
print(cookies)
fb.set_proxy('http://133.18.173.186:8080')
fb.set_cookies(cookies)

#post_url = ['https://www.facebook.com/animestory.animehk/photos/pcb.1035748480436588/1035747450436691/']
#for post in fb.get_posts('nintendo',options={'comments':True}):
#    print(post['text'][:50])
```

if I don't use facebook-scraper,how can i do?

I used to try selenium,but tag is so hard to catch.

Comment: What is wrong? The only thing the code does is to print cookies. It doesn't even try to fetch posts. Also Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. So don't be surprised when Facebook bans you.

Comment: Hello and good day dear aimerlover - many thanks for the question:  well i found out that we can scrape fb eg 

https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/

question: well can i scrape fb pages for a special key category - eg. 

female and  single  - is this possible!?